# $G$ is a finite group, if $ab^{-1}=ba^{-1}$ and $n$ is odd, then $a=b$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> $G$ is a finite group of order $n$, then if $a,b\in G : ab^{-1}=ba^{-1}$ and $n$ is odd, then $a=b$.

multiply both sides by $ab^{-1}$ we get $(ab^{-1})^2 = ab^{-1}ab^{-1}=ba^{-1}ab^{-1}=1$ so $ab^{-1}$ is of order $2$ or its $1\in G$ now we need to show that if $n$ odd then there's a single element of order $2$? I don't know how to do that...

Comment: Hint: Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: The order $(ab^{-1})$ must divide the order of $G$. When's that possible for odd $n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [Lagrange's theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Lagrange's_Theorem_%28Group_Theory%29), the order of any element $g \in G$ must divide the order of $G$, which is odd. Therefore, the order of $g$ can't be even.

> In particular $g=ab^{-1}$ can't have order $2$. It has therefore order $1$, since $(ab^{-1})^2=1$, i.e. $ab^{-1}=1$, or $a=b$.